# Generate report in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to generate a summary report in bash. My text file format's this way:

```
title:composer:price:musical pieces available:musical pieces sold
```

However, in my report output's supposed to be this way :

```
Title       Composer   Price   PiecesAvail   PiecesSold   TotalProfit
Graham      Jack       20.00       10            2           40.00
Zack        Squall      4.00       5             3            7.00
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction? I would have to either calculate the total profit beforehand,or while generating the report.

A sample of the textfile's here:

```
 Graham:Jack:20.00:10:2
 Jack:Squall:4.00:5:3
 Random - One:Jim:5.00:4:1
 RainyDay:Melissa:50.00:2:1
```

I've not thought how to calculate the total profit yet though.

Comment: As well as summarising the format of your file, it would be useful to see a short sample. How is the total profit calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

This script will read the text file and output if hopefully as you'd like..

- Each line from the text file goes into a variable called $line
- it loops over each line
- Using `cut -d ":" -f XX` it cuts a field number (separated by the delimiter `:`) from the $line variable
- I then use bc to do the aritmatic (using `let` will fail as numbers like 20.00 drive it mad)
- then finally it pipes the output through a function and `column` to make it look pretty

**foo.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "title composer price avail sold total"
function output(){
while read line
do
    title="$(cut -d ":"  -f 1 <<<"$line")"
    composer="$(cut -d ":" -f 2 <<<"$line")"
    price="$(cut -d ":" -f 3 <<<"$line")"
    avail="$(cut -d ":" -f 4 <<<"$line")"
    sold="$(cut -d ":" -f 5 <<<"$line")"
    #debug:
    #echo "title:$title, composer:$composer, price=$price, avail=$avail, sold=$sold" 
    total="$(echo "$price * $sold" | bc -l)"
    echo "$title $composer $price $avail $sold $total" 
done < file.txt
}
output | column -t
```

**file.txt**

```
Graham:Jack:20.00:10:2
Zack:Squall:4.00:5:3
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
stark@fourier ~ $ ./foo.sh
title   composer  price  avail  sold  total
Graham  Jack      20.00  10     2     40.00
Zack    Squall    4.00   5      3     12.00
```

Comment: What if I were to run it fully in a bash script though, without calling it in the terminal? Meaning,when I choose to generate report,the output should be there.

Comment: Firstly you could change `$1` inside foo.sh to the file.txt path

Secondly I'm afraid `column` can only render the column once all lines have been output.. so make a file called foo2.sh and tell it to run `foo.sh file.txt | column -t`

Alternatively use an alias

Also its possible to use cat EOF to create the script file and execute it.. so many ways that perl is definitely the winner here (in terms of elegance... its designed for this kinda situation)

Comment: Well, i can use only bash though. To render the output correctly, is that the only way?

Comment: Yop, I just remembered that it can be wrapped inside a function.. it will now work standalone.. don't forget to change `file.txt`    <3 bash :)

Comment: Regarding the code output | column -t, is it supposed to be outside the function? Or not? For the output I ran the fields are seperated by a single whitespace only,so I'm clarifying. :)

Comment: Yup thats correct, it'll work without `| column -t` but it won't align nicely for folks with long names for example..  all that the pipe into `column` does is dynamically output the result in a table. See `man column`

Comment: that's what I did,but the format's all over the place still. Does it have to do with the terminal length/width?

Comment: Yes that would be the reason it wraps.. you can pipe the output into a file to verify or reduce the font size on your terminal to verify I suppose

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to do this. The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. The correct solution is an awk script - see any of the other answers posted here.

Answer (score 2):

see if this is what you need:

```
kent$  awk -F':' -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{print "Title","Composer", "Price", "PA","PS","TotalP"}{"$1=$1";$(NF+1)=$3*$NF}7' f|column -t -s'    '
Title         Composer  Price  PA  PS  TotalP
Graham        Jack      20.00  10  2   40
Jack          Squall    4.00   5   3   12
Random - One  Jim       5.00   4   1   5
RainyDay      Melissa   50.00  2   1   50
```

- I've shorten the words in header, you can put the full words there
- the last `'    '` is `ctrl-v tab`
- the total Profit I just did as `Price * PieceSold`

Comment: What about adding in the text file in the line of code? Is there a need?

Comment: +1 Haven't seen `column` before, looks useful. @Zenix the name of the file goes at the end of the script. In the answer, the file is called `f`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue, using [Text::Table](http://p3rl.org/Text::Table):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::Table;

my $t = 'Text::Table'->new('Title',
                           'Composer',
                           'Price',
                           'Pieces Available',
                           'Pieces Sold',
                           'Total Profit',
                          );
while (<>) {
    my ($title, $composer, $price, $available, $sold) = split /:/;
    my $profit = sprintf '%.2f', $price * $sold;
    $t->add($title, $composer, $price, $available, $sold, $profit);
}

print $t;
```

Comment: Looks like a useful module. Are the single quotes around `'Text::Table'` valid? If so, what do they do?

Comment: @TomFenech: The quotes prevent Perl from interpreting it as a call to a `Text::Table` function and running the method `new` on its return value.

Comment: I second Tom. Module indeed looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty-printing columns can be fiddly, especially if the maximum length of each field is not known in advance. You can use `printf` in awk to do a reasonable enough job though:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN { printf "%12s%12s%8s%12s%12s\n", "Title","Composer","Price","PiecesAvail","PiecesSold"
}
{ printf "%12s%12s%8s%12s%12s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 }' file
```

I've specified the colon as the field separator using the switch `-F:`.

The `BEGIN` block prints the headers and every other line is printed using the same format. The format `%Ns` specifies a string padded to `N` characters, so it can be used for fixed width output.

I didn't calculate your total profit but that could be added in as an extra column. If for example it was as simple as `Price * PiecesSolid`, that would be `$3*$5` (column 3 multiplied by column 5). To show it as a number with two decimal places, you could add `%.2f` to the end of the `printf` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F':' '
BEGIN {
    fmt = "%-15s%-11s%5s   %11s   %10s   %11s\n"
    printf fmt, "Title","Composer","Price","PiecesAvail","PiecesSold","TotalProfit"
}
{ printf fmt, $1,$2,$3,$4"     ",$5"     ",sprintf("%.2f   ",$3*$5) }
' file
Title          Composer   Price   PiecesAvail   PiecesSold   TotalProfit
Graham         Jack       20.00       10            2           40.00    
Jack           Squall      4.00        5            3           12.00    
Random - One   Jim         5.00        4            1            5.00    
RainyDay       Melissa    50.00        2            1           50.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -- 'BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    OFS = "||"
    print "Title", "Composer", "Price", "PiecesAvail", "PiecesSold", "TotalProfit"
}
{
    sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $1); sub(/\r+$/, "", $5)
    printf "%s||%s||%5.2f||%6d||%6d||%8.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $5 * $3
}' "$@" | column -t -s '||'
```

Usage

```
sh script.sh file
```

Output:

```
Title           Composer    Price    PiecesAvail    PiecesSold    TotalProfit
Graham          Jack        20.00        10              2           40.00
Jack            Squall       4.00         5              3           12.00
Random - One    Jim          5.00         4              1            5.00
RainyDay        Melissa     50.00         2              1           50.00
```

Comment: Well,I can only use bash commands though. Is it possible to process the correct output and format it correctly,in bash but not calling any files?

Comment: @EdMorton I see.. Oh, no worries :)

Comment: @Zenix - awk is a standard UNIX tool, available on all UNIX installations just like sed, cut, grep, cat, etc. `column` is not such a tool (e.g. it is not present on Solaris) but you accepted an answer that uses `column` so I assume you're OK with that. So - what are you trying to tell us when you say `I can only use bash commands`?